# Webcam based object Scanner in C# 9/10 .net 6

Tags: python, c#, wpf, image-processing

Im trying to port this Python code from [theDataFox card_scanner_app](https://github.com/theDataFox/card_scanner_app) to an C# WPF Application.

The Python Programm uses a webcam to recognize a Object (Trading Card) and makes a Snapshot of the Object by pressing the Space bar.
As i know the Code Hashes the Snapshot and compares it to a database of  64.000 Images wich are already hashed.

Then the Code uses the Image ID, given in the Image Filename and generates the Output from the Database with all Informations about this specific Object.

```
import cv2
import pygame
import imutils
import numpy as np
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import KEYDOWN, K_q, K_s, K_SPACE
from . import util
import argparse
import glob

DEBUG = False

# calibrate this for camera position
MIN_CARD_AREA = 250000.0 / 3

# calibrate these
THRESHOLD = (100, 255)
FILTER = (11, 17, 17)

ROTATION = 0

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
def scan(img):
    # preprocess image
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray, FILTER[0], FILTER[1], FILTER[2])
    ret, gray = cv2.threshold(gray, THRESHOLD[0], THRESHOLD[1], cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    edges = imutils.auto_canny(gray)

# extract contours
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = [c for c in cnts if cv2.contourArea(c) >= MIN_CARD_AREA]

card, c = None, None
if cnts:
    # get largest contour
    c = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[0]

    # approximate the contour
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    pts = np.float32(approx)

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)

    # Find center point of card by taking x and y average of the four corners.
    # average = np.sum(pts, axis=0)/len(pts)
    # cent_x = int(average[0][0])
    # cent_y = int(average[0][1])
    # center = [cent_x, cent_y]

    # Warp card into 200x300 flattened image using perspective transform
    card = util.flattener(img, pts, w, h)
    card = util.cv2_to_pil(card).rotate(ROTATION)
return card, c, gray, edges


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
def detect(on_detect):
    dim = (800, 600)
    pygame.init()
    pygame.camera.init()
    cams = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
# print(cams)
display = pygame.display.set_mode(dim, 0)
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(cams[-1], dim)
cam.start()


capture = True
while capture:
    img = cam.get_image()
    img = pygame.transform.scale(img, dim)
    img = util.pygame_to_cv2(img)
    card, c, gray, edges = scan(img)


    # q to quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_q:
                capture = False
            elif event.key == K_s or event.key == K_SPACE:
                if card is None:
                    print('nothing found')
                else:
                    on_detect(card)

    # display
    if c is not None:
       cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 3)
    img = util.cv2_to_pygame(img)
    display.blit(img, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()

    if card is not None:
        card_img = util.pil_to_pygame(card)
        display.blit(card_img, (0, 0))

    if DEBUG:
        for layer in [gray, edges]:
            layer = cv2.cvtColor(layer, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
            layer = util.cv2_to_pygame(layer)
            layer.set_alpha(100)
        display.blit(layer, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()

cam.stop()
pygame.quit()
```

Now i'm trying to find a Solution to get similar Webcam Access with C# (Visual Studio).

As to i'm still an Beginner I have no Idea how to do this.

I tried several NuGet Packages and got nothing working. I guess my skills aren't good enough.

Therefor I now have to ask you, do you have any Ideas or Solutions that could do the given task?

I already ported most of the Programm and it's  working fine.
[This is my full Code](https://github.com/mikeGafert/MTG-Inventory)

Comment: OpenCV has VideoCapture, which can read from camera devices. the API is similar to pygame's camera, that is used in your python code. -- there are a few C# wrappers for OpenCV: opencvsharp, emgucv. just use those. you'll have mostly the same APIs as you have for the (official) python bindings for OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in webcam api directly in c#, the closest you can get is the [UWP video capture API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui). When I tried this, it did not work very well with my webcamera, but that might just be me.

There are lots of image processing libraries that have webcamera support built in. This includes OpenCV/[emguCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727747/how-to-get-video-stream-from-webcam-in-emgu-cv), but also for example [aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/samples/video.html).

I have used a "[versatile webcam library](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library)" that is a wrapper around the native webcam APIs, and it seem to work well.

More or less all of the libraries have good documentation with nice examples how to get images, many also have sample applications that demonstrate how to use the library, and this should be plenty to get you started. So "I tried and it didn't work" is not a good explanation. *What* have you tried? *Why* did it not work?